# Pass string from onLoadFinished method to another activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-contentprovider

I have created a content retriever which calls data from the content provider in another application, I can read the data successfully, but I want to pass the data from the onLoadFinished Method in my content retriever to an activity which should display the data on button press. But I am unsure of how to do it, I tried using a getter and setter, but it does not print anything.

Here are the rows in my content provider:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", "item"};
MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(columns);


matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{1, "FOUND"});

//Test is a string object that gets serialized to Json
matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{2, new Gson().toJson(test)});


matrixCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
return matrixCursor;
```

I want to get the data from the 2nd row and this is what I have in my `onLoadFinished` in my Retriever class:

```
class Retriever : LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private var dataFromJson = ""

//getters and setters
fun setData(data: String){
    this.dataFromJson = data
}

fun getData():String{
    return dataFromJson
}

//other Loader method such as onCreateLoader, etc.

override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, data: Cursor?) {
        try
        {
            val success: Boolean
            if (data != null && data.getCount() > 0)
            {
                data.moveToFirst()
                val dataString = data.getString(1)
                //this works, I am able to find the "found" text at the first row
                success = dataString.equals("FOUND", ignoreCase = true)
                //move to 2nd row
                data.moveToNext()
                //get data from 2nd row does not work
                val JSonData = data.getString(1)
                setData(JSonData)

            }
            else
            {
               Timber.d( "onLoadFinished Unknown error occurred")
                success = false
            }
            //custom interface listener
            listener.onClassListener(success)
        }
        catch (e:Exception) {
            Timber.d("Error")
        }
    }
  }
```

And in my activity when I create a Retriever object and call the getData() method, it displays nothing.

```
class TestActivity{
 private lateinit var dataRetriever: Retriever

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_activity)
        //I have a textView called dataTxt
       //displays nothing
        dataTxt.text = dataRetriever.getData()
    }
}
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the loading task is an async operation, when you call the `getData()` function, the value of `dataFromJson` is probably still an empty string.

To easily deal with this, you can declare an interface like this:

```
interface OnDataRetrieveListener{
    fun onDataLoad(dataString: String)
}
```

and then create an instance of it inside the Retriever

```
private lateinit var listener: OnDataRetrieveListener

fun setListener(listener: OnDataRetrieveListener){
    this.listener = listener
}
```

set the listener in your activity (if anonymously, it's like below):

```
 dataRetriever.setListener(object: Retriever.Listener{
        override fun onDataLoad(data: String) {
                    dataTxt.text = dataRetriever.getData()
        }
 })
```

callback the listener when the string is loaded in Retriever:

```
...
 val jsonData = data.getString(1)
 listener.onDataLoad(jsonData)
...
```

then the `dataTxt` will update

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for the answer, but I want to set the listener in a function, so when I click the button, I can call this `dataRetriever.setListener(object: Retriever.Listener{
        override fun onDataLoad(data: String) {
                    dataTxt.text = dataRetriever.getData()
        }
 })` But I get an error saying the listener is not initialised?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what do you mean by `set the listener in a function`, can you maybe provide some code?

Comment: no problem, I managed to solve that issue out. Thank you so much